# Can't Publish a WCF Project to IIS on my Dev SharePoint Server

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, sharepoint, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I have a Virtual Machine that I have setup to do SharePoint Development.  I am trying to test WCF Service interaction (external data lists).

When I go to publish my service from visual studio 2010 I get this error:

> Visual Web Developer does not support creating Web sites on a SharePoint Web server

OK, I thought.  I will just create the site.  So I went into IIS and created the site.  I then tried to deploy again (to http://localhost/MySiteName).  But I got the same Error!  I am confused because I have created the site.  I am just trying to deploy to it now.

What can I do to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try after renaming the `owssrv.dll` to `owssrv.dll_backup` at `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\50\isapi` folder.

Hope this will work for you.